# Calling event on another form

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am trying to make a value from a .xml file equal to a drop down box inside another form. In vb.net I can just call the form automatically, but inside C# I had to use the code `ApplicationProperties ApplicationPropertiesWindow = new ApplicationProperties();` to open the other form.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Declaring the XmlReader.
        XmlTextReader Reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\ForteSenderv2.0\Properties.xml");

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            switch (Reader.NodeType)
            {
                //Seeing if the node is and element.
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (Reader.Name == "BaudRate")
                    {
                        //Reading the node.
                        Reader.Read();
                        //Making the Baud Rate equal to the .xml file.
                        Form.ApplicationProperties.BaudRatebx.SelectedIndex = Reader.Value;
                    }
             }
         }
      }
```

Why can I not call the form using: 
`ApplicationPropertiesWindow.BaudRatebx.SelectedIndex = Reader.Value`

I am reading from a .xml file where the value of BaudRatebx is stored. I am trying to read from it and make the value from the .xml file equal to the BaudRatebx. The only problem is that BaudRatebx is on another form and I cannot call it because I do not know how, when I try to call the dropdown box it says **BaudRatebx is inaccessible due to its protection level**. There isn't any code for the BaudRatebx being declared as I did that in the designer.

Comment: What error are you getting?  I can see many reasons why you might have trouble, but without all of your code and a better explanation i am kinda lost.  Maybe cross threading issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, either.  How is `BaudRatebx` declared?

Comment: The form must be active to have anything set in it because the  the properties or form must be inialized first.

Comment: The reason why it works in vb.net is that it is a carry over from vb6 where it was used to access a default form object.

Comment: So how do I go about activating the form? I have the .xml file on the mainform load handler. I would like to start the program and have the value for BaudRatebx automatically set.

Comment: you do not want a pop form form.show() then you need to use a class not a form.

Comment: What is a pop form? So what you are saying is that if I have the BaudRatebx in a form I cannot access it?

Comment: you can form.show(0 or form.ShowDialog() will open the form and it popup. But I think you are just trying to use property if you are then you just need a class not a form.

Comment: Okay, I understadn what you are saying now. The second form `ApplicationPropertiesWindow` has an interface, so I bleieve it needs to be a form. I just want to be able to call the combo box on it from the main forms code, but I cannot figure out how to.

Comment: You can use the DropDown event to go get the list items each time it fires from some common source for all your forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Form1, add a public static field for the value and set it in your reader.

```
public static int BaudRatebx;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //Declaring the XmlReader.
            XmlTextReader Reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\ForteSenderv2.0\Properties.xml");

            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                switch (Reader.NodeType)
                {
                    //Seeing if the node is and element.
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        if (Reader.Name == "BaudRate")
                        {
                            //Reading the node.
                            Reader.Read();
                            //Making the Baud Rate equal to the .xml file.
                            BaudRatebx = int.Parse(Reader.Value);
                        }
                 }
             }
 }
```

Then in your other form's constructor after the `InitalizeProperties()` method put,

```
BaudRatebx.SelectedIndex = Form1.BaudRatebx;
```

Answer (score 1):

From you comments I think you want to in your ApplicationProperties have a getter like the one that follows:

```
public ComboBox GetComboBox
{
      get { return this.ComboBox; }
}
```

And in your Form1 you would want to:

```
ApplicationProperties ApplicationPropertiesWindow = new ApplicationProperties();
ApplicationPropertiesWindow .ShowDialog();
ComboBox comboBox = ApplicationPropertiesWindow.GetComboBox;
```

I hope this get you going in the right direction.